# Safari and Chrome can't redirect to local HTTPS Server

Tags: java, google-chrome, https, safari

I am relatively new to coding. I am trying to create a local HTTPS Server to redirect end-users after authenticating themselves to an authorization server using OAuth 2.0 (for a desktop application).

When the authorization server redirects to the HTTPS Server on Safari, "Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server "localhost." On Chrome, the browser throws "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET."

Here is the code used to generate the server:

```
public static void localServer() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(80), 0);
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
    server.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {});
    server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null);
    server.start();
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    String requestMethod = exchange.getRequestMethod();
    System.out.println(requestMethod);
    Headers requestHeaders = exchange.getRequestHeaders();
    if (!requestHeaders.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator it = requestHeaders.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry obj = (Entry) it.next();
            System.out.println(obj.getKey() + ":" + obj.getValue());
        }
    }
    InputStream is = exchange.getRequestBody();
    ByteArrayOutputStream requestBodyOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        requestBodyOutputStream.write(buffer, 0 , length);
    }
    System.out.println("Request Body: " + requestBodyOutputStream.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String response = "This is the response";
    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
    OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody();
    os.write(response.getBytes());
    os.close();
    }
}
```

When I turn the HttpsServer into an HttpServer and remove `SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");` and `server.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {});`, the server works; however, I would like the server to be a HttpsServer.

How should I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The port for HTTPS is 443. You used 80, which is reserved for HTTP. Browsers will use 443, if you open an HTTPS url.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; however, the error persists even after declaring `new InetSocketAddress(443)` and white-listing the new redirect URI.

Comment: Have you configured an SSL certificate? What details are given in the browser error messages?

Comment: I have not configured an SSL certificate. Would you mind explaining how to do so? The browser error message does not specify any other details besides the messages provided above.